# what do we mean when we say a programming language is a client server language

Tags: javascript

Example javascript is said to be a client-server programming language. I have tried browsing what that means. I seem not to grasp the meaning of that. So if javascript is seen as a client-server programming language what exactly does that mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can a programming language be both client and server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336868/can-a-programming-language-be-both-client-and-server-side)

Comment: It probably means that we can find it on both sides: client (in all modern browsers) and server (on certain servers having node.js running on it, possibly in connection with express).

Comment: I've NEVER heard any language described as a "client-server programming language", so I don't think it's a standard term. I guess it might be a clumsy way of referring to the fact that Javascript can be used for both client and server sides if desired.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript, that means that the it can run locally (in the browser) and on a server (not in the browser). That is simply the difference. For example, you cannot run any php on a browser, that makes it a server language, same for python.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a "client-server language" but can be described as a client-side programming language. However, this is not entirely correct. With node, it is also possible to use javascript on the server side. What does server-side vs. client-side mean?

Let's take PHP and Javascript. PHP is a pure server-side language. PHP is running on a computer that provides a server. This means that PHP can accept and process requests and send them back to the browser (for example). PHP therefore needs a server. Therefore server-side.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of programming languages regarding where they run, their nature and their functionalities **Client side** languages (aka frontend) and **Server side** languages (aka backend).

**Client side** languages are used to present data to user, it what a user sees and can interact with.

**Server side** languages are responsible for storing data, handling data etc.

Javascript started as a language that was mainly used on the **client side** of an app, until NodeJS came and by using Chrome's V8 engine was possible to run javascript on the **server side**.

So technically javascript is a language that can run in both cases, thus it is called client and server language.

This term though (client-server language) is kind of wrong in my opinion and i rarely heard of it.